# Avoid to make Socket.io connection twice

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I am using react at frontend and express on backend

I wrote the following code to connect client to backend

```
import React, { useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { io } from "socket.io-client"
const Video = () => {
    const [socket,setSocket] = useState(io("http://localhost:3001"));
    const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
    myVideo.muted = true;

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
        }).then(stream => {
            addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)

        })
    }, [])
```

But the socket onconnection event fired twice for a single webpage opening.
Please tell me where is the problem, what i add or remove to make only one connection per user .

Comment: you probably are in strict mode , wich means that your useEffect fires twice. An easy trick would be to add a useRef variable wich you would turn to true on first render, and you wold allow your useEffect to fire its content only when your useRef variable would be true, on the second render only

Comment: But I write

 ```io("http://localhost:3001"));``` 

in useState("")

is strictMode also effects on states??

Comment: try this trick : https://new.csb.app/. But thinking about this you probably should create a custome hook in wich you would call io only once thanks to a useEffect like the one in the example here

Answer (score 0):

try a useRef for debugging to see if strict mode is the problem:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const secondRender = useRef(false)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(()=> {
    secondRender.current && setCount(count => count +1)
    secondRender.current = true
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here you will see that the count stays at 1, so the functin in useEffect is only fired once

Comment: you are correct, count state don't increased to 2, 
As you intially said ,app is running under strict mode, the entire code runs twice, even I copied your provided code and  outer useEffect i console.log(count) it printed twice.
how i stop this double rendering by not disabling strict mode.

Comment: I got your point, to use a flag variable made by ```useRef()``` to make connection under ```useEffect()```. it will not make double connection . 
But I want to know there is any way to render whole component only once even we are under strict mode.

Comment: that's a good question, i don't think i know the answer to that :).

Comment: Thanks for your faster replies. your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty quickly here is an idea... it might be a bit falsy because i haven't tried it out, but the idea here is to extract you io call into a custom hook, and implement a condition so that your call is not called twice. You can probably improve this with a loader condition that does not return your socket if the call hasn't been successfull etc..

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react

const useIo = () => {
 const isSecondRender = useRef(false)
 const [socket, setSocket] = useState (null) 

 useEffect (()=>{
  isSecondRender.current && setSocket(io("http://localhost:3001"))
  isSecondRender.current = true
 },[])
 
 return socket
}
```